# Avatar image upload without page upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, upload

I want to add an avatar image upload feature to my project, and I was wondering if there exists any AJAX/jQuery solution for uploading an image without needing to refresh the page after uploading (the image uploads automatically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used http://www.uploadify.com/ in several projects and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this can do it, haven't tried it yet.

http://www.plupload.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe as target, to avoid full page reload:

```
<form method="post" action="your_action" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="myIframe">
   <input type="file" name="image" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload image" />
</form>

<iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe">
   //Post response will load here
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

trying update panel with a trigger DOES NOT WORK !!

**DOESNT NOT WORK:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"                                                           UpdateMode="Conditional" >
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Repeater ID="rpUploadedImages" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <img src='../Images/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImagePath")%>'/><br />
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnupload" EventName="click" />
   </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnupload" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="btnupload_Click" />
```

**DO WORK:**

so you have to go with placing the whole FileUpload tag in a separate page, and call it in iframe in your main page, and of course keep the "Upload" button in the iframe; so by click on the upload button the iframe alone will refresh without refreshing the whole page.
***(well tested)***